# How to change the default buttons of CKEditor

Tags: html, ckeditor, textarea

Sorry if this seems very simple, but I could not find the answer of my problem by searching the google.

I want to change the default layout of `CKEditor`. I have several textareas in the form that should be converted to ckeditor, so as the documentation has said, I changed class of them to:

```
class="ckeditor"
```

but when loading the form, all textareas open with full buttons in them while I want to filter some of the buttons. One obvious solution is to individually change the layout of each textarea. But, do you know any way to this in one step (like changing the default layout, if it exists at all)?

thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I found the answer from [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.toolbar)

// This is actually the default value.

```
config.toolbar =
[
    { name: 'document',    items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard',   items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms',       items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links',       items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert',      items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles',      items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors',      items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools',       items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
];
```

just delete items you don't want to be in your textarea

other default values also could be set via `config`